# Subset of functions with a finite number of non-zero roots

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So I'm working on a linear algebra exercises and one of them leaves me stumped: I can't figure out what's the relevance of the limitation.

So, I've got:

Function space F(R) = {f|f: R -> R} as a vectorspace.

F0(R) = {f in F(R)|f(x) =/= 0 with a finite number of x in R}.

Based on this I am to prove that F0(R) is a subset of F(R), but I'm not sure if I figured out the significance of the non-zero roots.

I concluded that with a finite number of non-zero roots, not all av + w belong to F0(R) since R is infinite, and therefore F0(R) is not a proper subset, but I can't but feel like I'm missing something. Should I use Cantor's proof of infinite real numbers or something here?

Comment: "I concluded that with a finite number of non-zero roots, not all av + w belong to F0(R)": do you have an example, then, of functions $v,w \in F_0(\Bbb R)$ and a constant $a \in \Bbb R$ such that $av + w \notin F_0(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Please be careful about terminology here: the term "non-zero root" is not standard (at least in the way that you seem to mean it). If you like, one common term for $\{x \in \Bbb R: f(x) \neq 0\}$ is the "support" of $f$. Otherwise, it'd be better to simply write "the $x$ at which $f(x)$ is non-zero".

Comment: Similarly, when you say that $F_0(\Bbb R)$ is "not a proper subset", I suspect that you meant to say that $F_0(\Bbb R)$ is not a **subspace** of $F(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks. The terminology issues are mostly a factor of me operating in a different language and not being familiar with the English vocabulary in the field. Given there's a finite number of roots, I just figured that while it's impossible to find one, there has to be one given the infinite number of possible inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that $F_0(\Bbb R)$ is actually meant to be the space of functions such that $\{x:f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is finite **or** $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Your conclusion that $F_0(\Bbb R)$ fails to be a subspace is incorrect. It is clear that if $f \in F_0(\Bbb R)$, then $af \in F_0(\Bbb R)$ for any $a \in \Bbb R$. You should try to convince yourself that if $f,g \in F_0(\Bbb R)$, then it must be true that $f + g$ is also an element of $F_0(\Bbb R)$.

---

As an example, consider the following functions $f,g \in F_0(\Bbb R)$. Take
$$
f(x) =  
\begin{cases}
1 & x \in \{1,2,\dots,10\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\qquad g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in \{2,4,\dots,20\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
We can see that for every value of $x$ outside the (finite) set $\{1,2,\dots,10\}\cup \{2,4,\dots,20\}$, it holds that $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) = 0$. Thus, $f + g \in F_0(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Can you extrapolate, why it is clear that $af \in F_0\mathbb{R}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$? Why can the function not land on one of the infinite number of real numbers that are not included in the map? It's clear I'm not understanding something here and it seems like this point right here is the rub: I'm somehow understanding the meaning of the relation wrong.

Comment: @JarnoPorkka I've added an example, perhaps you will find it helpful. If you explain why this example doesn't seem representative, maybe we can figure out what you're not understanding.